# Showing Location in a small widget

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, widget

I want to create a screen where it will show the location of the company in a small map on the screen when the longitude and the latitude is given.The map should not take up the whole page.The idea is to have a map like below. What is the best plugin to use and how to show it in a small widget?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [flutter_osm_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_osm_plugin) (Open Street Map) plugin.

I can resize the map widget by wrapping it with **[SizedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox-class.html)** widget.

#### Example

```dart
SizedBox(
  height: 200,
  width: double.infinity,
  child: OSMFlutter(...),
),
```

#### How it looks like

[image: OSM screenshot maps flutter]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [`google_maps_flutter`](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter), there is something called "Lite Mode" in Google Maps.

According to the [Google Developer docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/lite#overview_of_lite_mode):

> A lite mode map is a bitmap image of a map at a specified location and zoom level. Lite mode supports all of the map types (normal, hybrid, satellite, terrain) and a subset of the functionality supplied by the full API. Lite mode is useful when you want to provide a number of maps in a stream, or a map that is too small to support meaningful interaction.

**TL;DR**: Lite Mode is static image version of the Google Maps without any gesture enabled.

This mode is very useful to create something like mini map embed like you showed above. To use it in the flutter binding, we just need to specify `liteModeEnabled` to be `true`.

Lite Mode will come with two buttons, show the direction and open it in the Google Map app. If you don't want these buttons, disable it with `mapToolbarEnabled` to `false`.

```js
GoogleMap(
  liteModeEnabled: true,     // the required field
  mapToolbarEnabled: false,  // to disable buttons
  onTap: (latLng) =>         // onTap handler
      print('it is clickable'), 
  ...
);
```